# Load CSS based on network speed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, optimization, core-web-vitals

In Gmail, when my internet is slow, it shows a basic page with fewer colors, icons and animations. I want my React project to do something similar. I have two global SCSS files for my project, `index.scss` and `index-lite.scss`. How can I make it load the simpler CSS file when the network is slow to make my `First Contentful Paint (FCP)` faster?

Here is my main index.ts component code.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { configure } from 'axios-hooks';

import App from './components/App';
import API from './utils/api';
import store from './store';
import './index.scss';  **// or import './index-lite.scss';**


configure({ axios: API });

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Comment: you can use the navigator.connection API to check the user's network speed and conditionally load the appropriate CSS file.

Comment: Insightful Q, the navigator API can't be used as the browser support is not great (atm) ... I think the articles from [Web.dev by Google Dev's](https://web.dev/articles/defer-non-critical-css) would help you achieve the same if I'm not wrong... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [js navigator connection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/connection) to check slow internet speed and load the CSS files dynamically based on speed.

```
if (navigator.connection) {
  console.log(`Effective network type: ${navigator.connection.effectiveType}`);
  console.log(`Downlink Speed: ${navigator.connection.downlink}Mb/s`);
  console.log(`Round Trip Time: ${navigator.connection.rtt}ms`);
} else {
  console.log('Navigator Connection API not supported);
}
```

In the code snippet above, the effectiveType attribute provides a string that represents the effective type of the connection, and it could be 'slow-2g', '2g', '3g', or '4g'.

```
const fileref = document.createElement("link");
const filename = 'style.css' # based on speed
fileref.rel = "stylesheet";
fileref.type = "text/css";
fileref.href = filename;
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
```